# Need help in optimizing an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I came up with a query, to fetch data from a table, which contains **93781665** entries, to display the results as suggestions in an autocomplete text box.

But it takes more than **300 Sec** to fetch results.

The query is given below.

```
select * from table
where upper(column1||' '||column2||' '||column3) like upper('searchstring%') 
and rownum <= 10;
```

Kindly help me to optimize it.

Comment: Please provide the create table information. There might be some indexing etc wrong.

Comment: If you're searching with wild card at the end of the search string you're limiting search to column1 only on the other hand if you use `%searchstring%` you're searching concatenated 3 columns.So decide carefully depending on your search criteria create function based index on column 1 or concatenating 3 columns or if you're on 12c and above create virtual column and index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause in your query is not *sargable*, meaning that no index can be used there.  This rules out most of the methods you might use here to optimize the query.  Here is one suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE column4 LIKE 'SEARCHSTRING%';
```

Here, `column4` is a new column in your table, which contains the concatenation of the first three columns.  Furthermore, all text in `column4` will always be uppercase, and the search string you pass into the query will also always be uppercase.  Given these assumptions, the following index might help the query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (column4);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can index an expression:

```
create index idx_t_columns on t(upper(column1||' '||column2||' '||column3))
```

Then, this condition can use the index:

```
where upper(column1||' '||column2||' '||column3) like 'searchstring%'
```

If the search string is constant, then this should also work:

```
where upper(column1||' '||column2||' '||column3) like upper('searchstring%')
```

Note that a wildcard at the beginning of the `like` pattern would preclude the use of an index.